# How to convert json object into array in prestodb/athena

Tags: json, struct, presto, amazon-athena

I have a JSON object in this format `data = {"1": {"col1":"a", "col2":"b"}, "2": {"col1":"c", "col2":"d"}....,"99":{"col1":"asd", "col2":"exm"}}.` I would like to get all the values for col_1 and col_2 using athena. How do I achieve this using athena?

Comment: Is `data` a single record within your file which is stored on S3? Or is it a record within a particular column of a table? Also do you have any table defined in Athena/Glue? If so could you provide its definitions with `SHOW CREATE <table>`, please?)

Comment: Ok, the structure is like this { results:{ data : {"1": {"col1":"a", "col2":"b"}, "2": {"col1":"c", "col2":"d"}....,"99":{"col1":"asd", "col2":"exm"}}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it by converting it to Map and then unnesting it like

select key, value from table where
unnest(cast(json_parse(data) as Map(varchar,JSON)) as t(key,value))

Comment: I had to replace MAP(VARCHAR, JSON) with MAP<VARCHAR, JSON> and then it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Ignore that it is a JSON format (since it is not simple enough) and use the regex function:

```
SELECT regexp_extract_all(column_data, '"col1":"([a-z]+)",'); -- [a, c, ... asd]
```